# Redirect all domains to localhost

Tags: docker, aws

I'm using AWS Lambda.
To date, I have edited /etc/hosts but it is not possible to do it in Lambda.

I have a script that sends Ping to Google. And it looks like:

```
import subprocess

def aws_handler(a, b):
    ipaddress = 'google.com'  # guess who
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/ping', '-c', '3', ipaddress],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()

print(stdout, stderr)
```

My Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.8 as lambda-base
COPY  ./ ./
RUN yum install -y iputils dnsmasq
RUN echo "nameserver 127.0.0.1" > /etc/resolv.conf
RUN cat /etc/resolv.conf
RUN echo "address=/com/127.0.0.1" >> /etc/dnsmasq.conf
RUN cat /etc/dnsmasq.conf
FROM lambda-base
CMD [ "app.aws_handler" ]
```

When I run, I get the following output

```
(142.250.187.238): icmp_seq=1 ttl=127 time=68.3 ms\n64 bytes from lhr25s34-in-f14.1e100.net
(142.250.187.238): icmp_seq=2 ttl=127 time=67.6 ms\n64 bytes from lhr25s34-in-f14.1e100.net
(142.250.187.238): icmp_seq=3 ttl=127 time=...
```

When I expected the Ping to be 127.0.0.1. Why does it not work as expected?

Comment: Looks like it's doing exactly what you've asked, which is to run `ping -c 3 google.com`. I'd guess that `lhr25s34-in-f14.1e100.net` is the canonical machine name for one of the systems that responds to `google.com`

Comment: It should be 127.0.0.1

Comment: Did you check that exactly the same `dnsmasq.conf` works on a different system? I think you need to restart `dnsmasq` after modifying configuration files.

Comment: Probably the problem starts before, If I change the DNS server to the address of a server that does not exist for example 1.2.3.9 I still get the same result.That means the DNS change is not even successful

Comment: Oh I see. You want to use your dnsmasq to return 127.0.0.1 for all *.com addresses

Comment: Note that in many modern setups, name resolution may *ignore* `/etc/hosts` and/or `/etc/resolv.conf`, or only use them as a fallback of last resort.  Certain setups may also modify name resolution order/priority depending on context; Laptops can be configured to different name servers when connected to the corporate network versus public or home WiFi, for example. You will need to find out how the resolver is configured for that system.

Answer (score 1):

I have two lines in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`

```
no-resolv
address=/com/127.0.0.1
```

And the corresponding entry in `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

Then of course it's important to ensure that `dnsmasq` has been restarted to notice the new configuration

```
systemctl restart dnsmasq    # For systemd
# service dnsmasq restart    # Otherwise
```

Testing

```
ping -c1 bbc.com
PING bbc.com (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.061 ms
```